# vscode how to customize the bar theme in python interactive

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'd like to know which option of `workbench.colorCustomizations` I should set to modify the color of this blue bar. You can find it inside Python Interactive window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This setting work for me

```
"editor.lineHighlightBorder": "#480de8"
```

[image: "screen_shot"]